# Cannot create a new VS data connection in Server Explorer

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have a local instance of SQL Server 2008 express edition running on my development PC. I'm trying to create a new data connection through Visual Studio Server Explorer.

The steps are the following:

- Right click the "Data Connections" node => Choose Data Source.
- I select "Microsoft SQL Server" as the data source.
- The "Add Connection" dialog window appears. I select my local server instance => "Test connection" works fine.
- I select "AdventureWorks" as the database name => "Test connection" works fine.
- Next I hit the "Ok" button => Error message: **"This server version is not supported. Only servers up to MS SQL Server 2005 are supported."**

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 Professional Edition. The target framework of the application is ".NET framework 3.5". I have a reference to System.Data (framework v2.0) and cannot find another version of the assembly on my system.

Am I referencing the wrong assembly? How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Hm. Since you so easily found the answer searching, it seems this question/answer is not needed. I vote to delete it.

Answer (score 2):

I hadn't thought of googling the error message to try and find a fix to this problem. It turns out it can easily be fixed by installing SP1 for SQL Server 2008.